# How to select a whole line except beginning tab/space and last enter?

Tags: visual-mode, cursor-motions, object-motions

I'm dealing with the following text and want to select "abc def":

```
    123
    abc def
    456_4
```

I've tried `viw` but it can only select a whole word isolated by spaces, and `v$` starting with cursor on "a" which selects both "abc def" but also the last Enter unexpectedly.

Any way to only select "abc def" precisely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use `v$` if you follow it with `h`. But there's a better motion we can use than `$`, i.e. [`g_`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#g_). This moves *to the last non-blank character of the line*.

So...

```
vg_
```

Since you mentioned text objects ([`iw`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#iw)), it's worth noting that you can precede them with a count.

As long as the cursor is on one of the letters of `abc`, this will select the desired text:

```
v3iw
```

Alternatively, with [`aw`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#aw):

```
v2aw
```